# What's wrong with the Sum function?

Tags: summation, assignment, index

Here are the codes:

```
f[n_]:=Sum[1,{K,0,n},{M,0,n-K},{La,0,K},{Lb,0,n-K-M},{Lc,0,M}]//Simplify

g[n_]:=Sum[1,{La,0,n},{Lb,0,n-La},{Lc,0,n-La-Lb},{K,La,n-Lb},{M,Lc,n-K-Lb}]//Simplify

f[x]/.x->5

g[x]/.x->5

f[5]

g[5]
```

it gives results like

> `252 196 252 252`

The two summation are actually identical but with the indices in different order, I guess there's some problem with the Sum function.

The question is that why assign a value to `n` then calculate the summation is different from that calculate the summation first then do the assignment, for the function `g[n]` defined about.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, but you should avoid using `K` for an index or variable, because it is a reserved symbol in *Mathematica*. In general, it is a good idea to avoid user-defined symbols/functions that start with capital letters in order not to conflict with built-in functions.

Comment: Confirmed in v10.0.1 on Mac OS 10.10.5. I agree it's a bug, but I'd prefer more input from the community before adding the `bugs` tag.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new here. And I hope to enjoy in the community. I guess it's a bug, I just wonder why it happens and how to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: So, 6 confirmations. I think we can consider it a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

"11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"

Clear[f, g]

f[n_] := Sum[
  1, {K, 0, n}, {M, 0, n - K}, {La, 0, K}, {Lb, 0, n - K - M}, {Lc, 0, M}]

g[n_] := Sum[
  1, {La, 0, n}, {Lb, 0, n - La}, {Lc, 0, n - La - Lb}, {K, La, n - Lb}, {M, 
   Lc, n - K - Lb}]
```

The symbolic closed-form functions are not equivalent.

```
f[n] // FullSimplify

(*  1/120 (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (4 + n) (5 + n)  *)

g[n] // Simplify

(*  1/12 (1 + n) (2 + n)^2 (3 + n)  *)

Solve[f[n] == g[n], n]

(*  {{n -> -3}, {n -> -2}, {n -> -1}, {n -> 0}, {n -> 1}}  *)
```

However, [**`FindSequenceFunction`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) applied to sequences generated from either `f` or `g` give the symbolic closed-form function for `f`

```
f[n] == FindSequenceFunction[f /@ Range[7], n] // Simplify

(*  True  *)

f[n] == FindSequenceFunction[g /@ Range[7], n] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that.

Testcode: (The sums are giving out different identities (the second one is wrong) while NSum works as expected.)

```
a=Sum[1,{K,0,n},{M,0,n-K},{La,0,K},{Lb,0,n-K-M},{Lc,0,M}]
b=Sum[1,{La,0,n},{Lb,0,n-La},{Lc,0,n-La-Lb},{K,La,n-Lb},{M,Lc,n-K-Lb}]
TrueQ[FullSimplify[a==b]]
({a,b}/.n->#)&/@Range[1,10]
{NSum[1,{K,0,#},{M,0,#-K},{La,0,K},{Lb,0,#-K-M},{Lc,0,M}],NSum[1,{La,0,#},{Lb,0,#-La},{Lc,0,#-La-Lb},{K,La,#-Lb},{M,Lc,#-K-Lb}]}&/@Range[1,10]
```

Seems to be a bug in [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html).

```
$Version
```

> 11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)

Also confirmed by my other machine:

> 10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)

Comment: Same result, "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"